# Cannot fetch using https domain unless tunneling through ngrok in react native expo

Tags: react-native, flask, ssl, expo, cors

I am facing the following issue.

I am using this function and it works when setting the `backendDomain` to an ngrok `https://something.ngrok-free.app` and that points to `https://mylovely.app`

**The function**

```
  const get_bookings = () => {
    console.log(backendDomain);
    fetch(`${backendDomain}/api/v1/booking`)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => dostuff(data))
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error fetching car booking: ", error);

        // Initialize an empty array to hold error details
        let errorDetails = [];

        // Check if it's an Error object and has a message property
        if (error instanceof Error && error.message) {
          errorDetails.push(`Message: ${error.message}`);
        }

        // Check for HTTP status if it's an HTTP error (useful when using libraries like axios)
        if (error.response && error.response.status) {
          errorDetails.push(`Status: ${error.response.status}`);
        }

        // Check for custom fields that your errors might have
        if (error.code) {
          errorDetails.push(`Code: ${error.code}`);
        }

        // Convert the errorDetails array to a string
        const errorString = errorDetails.join(", ");

        // Stop loading and display error
        console.log(errorString);
        // ToastAndroid.show(errorString, ToastAndroid.LONG);
      });
  };
```

When I run:

- `npx expo start --web` backendDomain=`https://mylovely.app` it works.
- `npx expo start -c --tunnel` backendDomain=`https://mylovely.app` it does not work.
- `npx expo start -c --tunnel` backendDomain=`https://something.ngrok-free.app` it works.
- When I install the apk backendDomain=`https://mylovely.app` it does not work.
- When I install the apk backendDomain=`https://something.ngrok-free.app` it works.

I have SSL certs from GoDaddy. Obviously, https://mylovely.app is reachable because I can reach it through `ngrok` and I also visited/tested through the browser and Postman.

my flask_cors is a simple     `cors = CORS(resources={r"/api/*": {"origins": "*"}})`

```
package.json

{
  "name": "mainapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^19.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/clipboard": "^1.5.1",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "7.2.0",
    "@react-native-community/progress-bar-android": "^1.0.5",
    "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.11.0",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.5.1",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.8",
    "axios": "^1.5.0",
    "deprecated-react-native-prop-types": "^4.2.1",
    "expo": "~49.0.10",
    "expo-application": "~5.3.0",
    "expo-clipboard": "~4.3.1",
    "expo-constants": "~14.4.2",
    "expo-device": "~5.4.0",
    "expo-router": "^2.0.0",
    "expo-screen-orientation": "~6.0.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "formik": "^2.4.4",
    "luxon": "^3.4.3",
    "ngrok": "^5.0.0-beta.2",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-datepicker": "^4.18.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.5",
    "react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.9",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.3",
    "react-native-input-spinner": "^1.8.1",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^17.1.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.10.6",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
    "react-native-searchable-dropdown": "^1.1.3",
    "react-native-timeline-flatlist": "^0.8.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.0",
    "react-native-web": "^0.19.8",
    "react-native-webview": "13.2.2",
    "react-resource-timeline": "^1.1.0",
    "react-scroll-sync": "^0.11.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3",
    "yup": "^1.3.1",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.18.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "eslint": "^8.51.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "private": true
}


component.js

import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, TextInput, Button } from "react-native";
import { Text } from "react-native-elements";
// import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import { EXPO_PUBLIC_BACKEND_DOMAIN } from "@env";
// import { ToastAndroid } from "react-native";
import axios from "axios";

const SettingsScreen = () => {
  const [backendDomain, setBackendDomain] = useState(
    "https://something.ngrok-free.app"
  );

  const dostuff = (data) => {
    // ToastAndroid.show(JSON.stringify(data), ToastAndroid.LONG);
    console.log(data);
  };

  const get_bookings = () => {
    console.log(backendDomain);
    fetch(`${backendDomain}/api/v1/booking`)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => dostuff(data))
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error fetching car booking: ", error);

        // Initialize an empty array to hold error details
        let errorDetails = [];

        // Check if it's an Error object and has a message property
        if (error instanceof Error && error.message) {
          errorDetails.push(`Message: ${error.message}`);
        }

        // Check for HTTP status if it's an HTTP error (useful when using libraries like axios)
        if (error.response && error.response.status) {
          errorDetails.push(`Status: ${error.response.status}`);
        }

        // Check for custom fields that your errors might have
        if (error.code) {
          errorDetails.push(`Code: ${error.code}`);
        }

        // Convert the errorDetails array to a string
        const errorString = errorDetails.join(", ");

        // Stop loading and display error
        console.log(errorString);
        // ToastAndroid.show(errorString, ToastAndroid.LONG);
      });
  };


  return (
    <View>
      <Text h4>Backend Domain:</Text>
      <Text>{EXPO_PUBLIC_BACKEND_DOMAIN}</Text>
      <TextInput
        value={backendDomain}
        onChangeText={setBackendDomain}
        placeholder="Enter Backend Domain"
        style={{ borderWidth: 1, padding: 10, marginBottom: 20 }}
      />
      {/* <Button title="Save" onPress={saveBackendDomain} /> */}
      <Text>Current Backend Domain: {backendDomain || "Not set"}</Text>
      <Button title="TEST" onPress={get_bookings} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default SettingsScreen;
```

**NOTE:** same issue using axios
**SUSPICIONS** might be a cors issue?

Comment: It was an ssl issue i will update the question with a simplified example soon.